# Border from hidden collapsible menu is visible

Tags: html, css, menu, sidebar

I have created a collapsible menu, but while the menu is hidden, the border is visible. I want it to make it invisible when it is collapsed, but i want the menu to have a border. How can i do that?

[screenshot](https://prnt.sc/owls95)

```css
.container {
  height: 270px;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 25%;
  background-color: lightgray;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  border: 5px solid #0073aa;
}

.container-inner {
  margin-left: 18px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container">
  <div class="container-inner">
    <a class="close" onclick="closeMenu()">&times;</a>

    <button class="resize">A-</button>
    <button class="resize">A+</button>
    <button class="contrast">Contrast</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont recommend using `margin` or `width` as the properties to show/hide an element. You are seeing the border because of the quirks of margin-collapse. Using `position: absolute` and `transform: translateX()` to position and hide it out of view and change the transform value to move it into view would likely behave more as you expect.

Comment: The container-inner class, is just for the content of the container, because i want the buttons to be a little to the right for example. It has nothing to do with the border showing while the container is hidden.

Comment: The border is visible because it exists. A div with `width: 0` and a border will still show the border. Use your inspector you will see an element with 10px of width (5px border-left + 5px border-right). Maybe apply the border to the inner div if you expect it to be hidden.

Comment: What do you do to show this content (I'm assuming you animate the width)?  Why not just start the border width on zero too and then when you animate the width, animate the border width too

Comment: @Pete Thank you! That did it! I didnt even think about it. I just made it 0 when it is collapsed!

Comment: why are you not using display:block; and display:none; inside the main div and using javascript to trigger that?